# CORBA test automation

Tags: java, c++, corba

Assuming there is a big application built using `C++` & others and `CORBA` as a way of interacting with it, is there any viable way of simulating user interaction, with the goal of running ANY kind of automated testing (the automation is less of an issue)?
The preferred approach would involve using JAVA, but that is also less of an issue.

Google provides almost nothing on this.

Comment: I don't see how you can expect Google to know how to write CORBA clients to interact with your distributed components.  There's nothing else to say except "get a shovel".  Start writing those clients.

Comment: I was thinking more in the way: has it been done? and more so, could anyone point me to an actually 'live' or working API for java which would allow me to play around with it. I'm really grasping for straws, any pointer would be good.

Comment: I'm sure it's been done, but each one is specific to the CORBA app.  I don't believe anything like SOAP UI exists for CORBA; it's a proprietary protocol, after all. That's why web services have won the day over CORBA.

Comment: JRE's ORB has some support for dynamic invocations (javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/ORB.html). So if you're looking for a way to build generic tool to test CORBA interfaces, you might start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IONA (now owned by Progress) built a product called the [Orbix Code Generation Toolkit](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/gen3/33/html/orbixcgt33_pguide/chap_overview.html) that does exactly this. It's available in Orbix v3 through v6.

It walks your IDL documents and produces client (or even server) code to completely exercise and call each method available with random but valid values for each parameter, printing them out each time.

You'll need to get [Orbix](http://www.progress.com/en/orbix/index.html) to use it, but maybe you can get an eval license for it to try it out by contacting Progress Software. And don't worry, you can generate client code that can run against any CORBA-compatible server, not just Orbix ones.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the product offers a CORBA API, and I assume that there is an existing client that interacts with the server using only that API (this is called eating your own dog food). 
CORBA is designed to be language agnostic, so you can certainly write a Java client to interact with it.

Given those assumptions then you could feasibly test the server using the CORBA interface, but you will not be able to test the client-side code such as buttons and dialogs etc. You could use UI testing franmeworks for that.